# How to go to a View Controller after launch screen in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to launch an app. I get the splash screen, but then I pointed main to a custom view controller named `LoginController.xib`. So, after the splash screen, I get a crash and the error says:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7fed19c036d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'`

Is it necessary to point the Main Screen to `Main.storyboard`? How can I make this work?

Comment: Please post your code, i am sure i'll be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ViewController inside a storyboard, you can mark it as initial view controller and set Main Interface with this storyboard, but if your viewcontroller with nib file (.xib), set Main Interface empty and set the window root view to your viewController

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let vc = LoginController()
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

[image]